# uniformly and pointwise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ deﬁned on $[0,1]$ by $f_n(x) = x^n$. Show that the sequence converges to the function

$f(x) = 0 $ if $ x ∈ [0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x = 1$

pointwise on $[0,1]$, but not uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Surely you can make out why , at least pointwise, the sequence is converging to the function above.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the standard deal, if $|x|<1$, then 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^n=0
$$
since it is a monotone decreasing sequence bounded below.

If $x=1$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^n=1$.

As the limit is not a continuous function, and each $f_n$ is continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to note that the sequence converges pointwise to $f$. Surely, set $x=1$ and you get a constant sequence. And, for any $x\in[0,1)$, the sequence converges monotonically to $0$. I am not including the details of the proof.

Now, observe that , for any $x_0\in(0,1)$
$$|x_0|^n<\epsilon \text{ iff. }  n>\dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln x_0}$$

Assume that the sequence was uniformly convergent. So, for any $x_0\in(0,1)$
$$n>K\implies|x_0|^n<\epsilon$$
for some $K.$ And, since the choice of $x_0$ is arbitrary, it is necessary that 
$$K\ge \dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln x_0}$$

But, it should be noted that 
$$\lim_{x_0\to1^-}\dfrac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln x_0}=\infty$$
which poses a contradiction. So, it can't be uniformly convergent.